# Wordpress Plugin Authoring question about jquery and css

Tags: plugin-development, css, wp-enqueue-script

When I'm writing a plugin, do I assume that jquery is included, or should I always wp_enqueue_script it and let wordpress figure it out?

Also, what's the best practice for getting an image path figured out in my bundled css file?

Answer (score 1):

One point for using `wp_enqueue_script` is for that very reason. Never assume anything, enqueue jQuery so that if it is there already it does nothing, but if not , it will queue it up.

If your talking about the image path for your plugin, you can use the following, http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

The examples for `plugins_url` should help.